# Ascending an already Descending result?

Tags: sql

I'm finishing off an online course on SQL, and one of these questions aren't very clear in what they mean.

The question:
"everyone’s name is getting called in alphabetical order by last name and then by first name.

Find the last 5 names that will be called at graduation in the reverse order in which they will be called.

Return a table with the first and last name only.

You can assume that everyone in the Person table is graduating."

Basically, the part that confuses me is the:

'''in the reverse order in which they will be called'''

Lol I need this assignment done soon, and my Teacher's constantly off.

I've tried to get assistance from my teacher, and tried messaging the website but I've never gotten a reply in my life.
I also asked my colleges but their completely confused too.

```
SELECT PERSON.last_name, PERSON.first_name
FROM PERSON
GROUP BY PERSON.first_name
ORDER BY PERSON.last_name DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

EXPECTED RESULTS:

```
FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME
Arthur     | Weasley
Kevin      | Whitby
Oliver     | Wood
Blaise     | Zabini
Rose       | Zeller
```

---

ACTUAL RESULTS:

```
FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME
Rose       | Zeller
Blaise     | Zabini 
Oliver     | Wood
Kevin      | Whitby 
Arthur     | Weasley
```

I need the names in alphabetical order but somehow I need the last names of the table (99 entires long).

Comment: Your "Actual Results" fit all the criteria of the question. Essentially "The last 5 students that will be called, in reverse order". Is this some shitty only thing that won't accept your very correct results? The only edit I would suggest is that you do `ORDER BY PERSON.last_name DESC, PERSON.first_name DESC` to better fit the question.

Comment: @JNevill It's on CodeHS, and many other projects are a lil janky aswell, I hope it's the website :/

Comment: I mean.. I guess you could do like... `ORDER BY last_name, first_name LIMIT 5 OFFSET 95` but that just isn't the way we do things in the real world. Like... I don't know how many students are in the table to graduate and hard code that into my SQL if I did...  I dunno.

Comment: Or, and this seems equally silly. Wrap you select into a subquery and then reorder it outside. Editted - Gordon's suggestion, basically.

Comment: Seeing `LIMIT` in SQL dialect i assume you use MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite or PosgreSQL as RDMS and because of the invalid `GROUP BY` usage i am assuming you are using MySQL/MariaDB .. Please check what you are using and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23989205) the tags

Answer (score 1):

Your query was close, but needs to be sorted by first name too. For example there could be a Ron Weasley that should be in the final five

```
SELECT TOP 5 first_name, last_name
FROM PERSON
ORDER BY last_name desc, first_name desc
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23987589)

Comment: [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag does not indicate SQL Server (MSSQL) SQL dialect on this website.. SQL tag is about writting valid ANSI/iSO standard SQL.. Also the included SQL dialect in the question includes `LIMIT` so i assume the topicstarter uses MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite or PosgreSQL as RDMS also because of the invalid `GROUP BY` usage i am assuming the topicstarter is using MySQL/MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

First, `GROUP BY` is not needed.  You should recognize this at this point in the course.  If there are duplicates (which are unlikely in such a table), use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Second, based on the results, they want the result *in the order they will be called*.  For that, use a subquery:

```
SELECT last_name, first_name
FROM (SELECT P.last_name, P.first_name
      FROM PERSON P
      ORDER BY P.last_name DESC, P.first_name DESC
      LIMIT 5
     ) P
ORDER BY last_name;
```

And the answer to the question they asked is basically your query without the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT P.last_name, P.first_name
FROM PERSON P
ORDER BY P.last_name DESC, P.first_name DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the changes didn't work :( I believe it could possibly be the website (CodeHS) which is stopping the code from working correctly. But thanks for your help anyways :)